# Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'str'>'

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, rpy2

I am trying to run R in a google collab notebook (which worked fine before, however as I now tried to access it and run it it keeps giving me an error).

I have ran the following:

```
    %load_ext rpy2.ipython

    %%R 
    install.packages('rworldmap')
    install.packages('classInt')
    install.packages('reshape2')
    install.packages('dplyr')
    install.packages('ggpubr')
```

NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'str'>'

I have tried re-opening the notebook or creating a new one but I keep having the same issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a problem with newer versions. You must downgrade rpy: run in a cell:

`!pip install rpy2==3.5.1`

restart and try again

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74206306/rpy2-error-in-django-conversion-py2rpy-not-defined-for-objects-of-type-cla) post.

Comment: Hi, +1 on your answer. Thank you. Related question, do you happen to know why, when using `%%R` on a Colab document `options(repr.plot.width=30, repr.plot.height=2)` does not work, and what to do to change the size of the plot in R?

Comment: I posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74721350/4089351).

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you first uninstalled the currently loaded `rpy2` package:

```
!pip uninstall rpy2 -y
```

Then install an older version of `rpy2` (3.0.0, works for me):

```
!pip install rpy2==3.0.0
```

Use magic commands and enjoy R&python interactively:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Example:

```
%%R
x<-1:5
x
```