# How to specify the plot size in R when using the rpy2 package in the Python runtime within a Google Colab doc

Tags: python, r, plot, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use both RStats and Python in the same document with Google Colab. This is the [background idea](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-r-in-google-colab-b6e02d736497) with some modification for the package iteration as follows:

```
!pip install rpy2==3.5.1 --quiet
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

followed by

```
%%R
reg <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

options(repr.plot.width=15, repr.plot.height=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,4))
plot(reg)
```

It works computationally; however, the adjustment of the plot size is ignored completely, rendering the following squeezed output:

[image]

How can I adjust the width and height of the plot in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width, hight and unit to your Rmagic:

```
%%R -w 1480 -h 780 -u px
```

Solved it for me.
Hope it helps or that you already have a solution!